# Why does Gantt not work in Modern?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, gantt-view

I have made a list in SharePoint Online.

The list has a few views, among them a Gantt view.

It works perfect when  create it. I can see Gantt view fine.

However when I switch views the Gantt stops working.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gantt Views are still not supported in SharePoint Online Modern experience.

When you create a new Gantt View then it creates a new page with `listUrl/GanttViewName.aspx` and opens this page.

But when you shift to another view modern experience then it redirects/refreshes page with different URL (When you change view in classic experience it redirects to another page with view name and URL).

In Modern experience when you change the view it does not redirect to another page. It only appends the view ID in URL like `?viewid=1776df08-b782-4f90-9b6d-62b7c3501b09` and renders the new view in same place(on same page) without redirecting it to another page.

As, gantt views are not supported in modern experience, But you still want to use gantt chart then I would suggest using classic experience.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Ganesh said, Gantt Views are still not supported. Until now, Microsoft haven't  releases a modern UI for Tasks Lists. You may need to use classic experience or use SPFx to create you own solution.

Answer (score 0):

As of mid 2022, I can confirm that Gantt views of tasks list is available in Modern Sharepoint. There are a lot of old articles on the internet which say it cannot be done. I guess MS may have added this view afterwards.